# How to create a db table using xlsx file as a input using pyspark

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, pyspark

I need to create a db table using xlsx file as a input. I am able to use the below code for csv file and create a table using below code. But is there a way to use the xlsx file and create a db table.

```
info=spark.read.option("delimiter", ";").csv("/home/temp/data.csv", header=True)

info.show(4)

info.write.format("parquet").option("path", "/prj/db_info/database_external/mode").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("db_info.coll_stud_data")

spark.sql("describe table db_info.coll_stud_data").show()
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

to work with XLSX files in spark, use spark-excel package from https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

launch the pyspark terminal using `pyspark --packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.13.1`

```
info = spark.read
    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
    .option("sheetName", "<sheetname>")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("/home/temp/data.xlsx")

spark.sql("describe table db_info.coll_stud_data").show()

info.write.format("parquet").option("path", "/prj/db_info/database_external/mode").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("db_info.coll_stud_data")
```